# How to reference generic type parameter of generic type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Entity interface:

```
public interface Entity<Id>
{
    Id getId();
}
```

and the Dao:

```
public interface Dao<T extends Entity<Id>, Id>
{
    T find(Id id);
}
```

If I try to remove the second type parameter on Dao (Id) I get "Id cannot be resolved to a type". My question is if it's somehow possible to get rid of the second type parameter on Dao as it's essentially redundant.

To be clear, I'm trying to avoid having to repeat the Id type everywhere that I'm using the Dao. It should be enough to specify that type once in the Entity interface.

As it's now I have to repeat myself like this:

```
private Dao<Car, UUID> carDb;
```

everywhere that I'm using the Car Dao.

Comment: Given that the interface doesn't talk about *T* at all, wouldn't it be better to remove T than Id? Or did you mean the `find` method to return `T`?

Comment: I want people that use the Dao to be forced to give Dao a real entity class as a type parameter, such as Car (which implements Entity), Only having Entity, without T, leads to "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)".

Comment: You're correct that the find method should return T, that works. Edited question.

Comment: As written it is not redundant at all.

Comment: Edited the question so you'll see what's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible.

in  `Dao<T extends Entity<Id>, Id>` second type parameter `Id` is not redundant in the sense that  `Dao` is parametrized over two type parameters, one bounded type `T` and other `Id`, Also, `Entity` is parametrized over `Id`. (see the difference, `by this you are restricting the type parameter of Entity to be same as second type parameter of Dao`)

Its possible only in the case the compiler already knows the Type argument of Entity.

```
interface Dao<T extends Entity<String>> {
    T find(String id);
}
```

Comment: That's what I suspected. I'll leave the question open a while longer in case someone comes up with an alternative solution.